# VSCode extension to "do stuff" on VSCode events, like "new window"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an extension that will do configured things on VSCode events, like "new window"?  I'm looking for something that will, for example, open certain files in my workspace whenever launching VSCode on that workspace.  Or maybe just run a script (on the remote side).

(I've looked in open-vsx.org but can't find anything under search terms I've thought of.)

(Or if there is a non-extension way to do it built-in that I'm not aware of ...)

Comment: if you can't find one in the marketplace you can write it yourself

Comment: @rioV8 - On SO comments don't have to be helpful, thanks though.

Comment: I can write such an extension